# SQL Server Merge Replication publishing an article

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We are using SQL Server 2012 and are publishing an article (table). When we check the status in the `sysmergearticles` table the status is and remains 6 even though the data is replicating. We can't figure out why it does not change to 2. Any help appreciated.

We would have expected it to turn to 2 after running a new snapshot and replicating.